# Using “old” 5W iPhone 5 Power adapter to charge a new iPhone XR

Tags: iphone, charger

I would like to know if it is safe to use an “old” 5W Power Adapter (charging brick) from an iPhone 5 to charge my new iPhone XR. I am specifically referring to the original (and, of course, genuine) charging brick that my old iPhone 5 included in the box.

Yeah, I know that my new iPhone XR already includes a cable and a 5W Power Adapter. However, I would like to have two chargers (one at my work and the other one at home).

I would definitely need to purchase a new lightning cable, but, my question is, Is it necessary to purchase a new charging brick? Could the “old” charging brick damage my new phone (since it is too old)? It seems to work fine. It worked perfectly with my iPhone 5, but I am not sure if I should use it on my iPhone XR.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if it is safe to use an “old” 5W Power Adapter (charging brick) from an iPhone 5 to charge my new iPhone XR.

**Yes**.

> Is it necessary to purchase a new charging brick?

**No**.

> Could the “old” charging brick damage my new phone (since it is too old)?

**No**. As it is working fine with an iPhone 5, it will be fine to use it with iPhone XR.

So, **yes**, it will be fine using the old power adapter from your iPhone 5 to charge your iPhone XR.

Comment: what about the cord? Can we use iPhone 5 cord instead of XR cord?

Comment: @Ibo yes, you should be fine. The cable provided by Apple in box with both the phones are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 5s and iPhone X chargers are compatible with each other because both phones use the lightning adapter, so yes you can use your power adapter to charge your iPhone XR.